# Secrets Manager Update Secret - Secret String additional JSON Encoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cli, x509certificate, aws-secrets-manager

I am using the AWS CLI to update a JSON secret containing x509 certificates. The payload that I am passing into the `--secret-string` parameter is the encoding I am expecting, but secretsmanager is performing additional encoding of the newline characters when it is uploaded and stored in AWS.

**Problem**

The problem I am getting is the PEM and Key contents are not entirely being unescaped when unmarshalling the secret. I have an application server in Go that when passing the secrets into `tls.X509KeyPair()` it is unable to recognize the contents of the certificates.

I can paste the payload from the CLI command into the secret manually on the web and it retains the existing formatting and my code works fine.

I am primarily looking to see if there is something I can do to fix the upload encoding instead of having to format / unescape the PEM/Key contents in Go when fetching the secret.

**Example**:

CLI Command:

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id my-secret --secret-string '{"PEM":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n...\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","KEY":"..."}'
```

Actual Uploaded Secret:

```
{"PEM":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\\\\n...\\\\n...\\\\n...\\\\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\\\\n",,"KEY":"..."}
```

I am using `awk` to join the PEM contents and `jq` for updating + stringifying the JSON. The stringified JSON is the correct format I am looking for.

awk: `STRING_PEM=$(awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' $PemFile)`

jq: `SECRET_STRING=$(jq -r 'tostring' $UPDATED_SECRET)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that a secret set by this command

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id my-secret --secret-string '{"PEM":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...\n...\n...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n","KEY":"..."}'
```

works as expected (see the Go demo at the bottom of this answer).

**And here is a simplified command that does the whole thing**:

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id -secret --secret-string "$(jq -n --arg cert "$(cat /path/to/cert/file)" --arg key "$(cat /path/to/key/file)" -c '{"PEM": $cert, "KEY": $key}')"
```

Here is a Go demo used to verify the uploaded content:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/secretsmanager"
)

func main() {
    secretName := "test1"
    region := "ap-southeast-1"

    config, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion(region))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    svc := secretsmanager.NewFromConfig(config)

    input := &secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String(secretName),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetSecretValue(context.TODO(), input)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var secret struct {
        PEM string `json:"PEM"`
        KEY string `json:"KEY"`
    }
    {
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(*result.SecretString), &secret); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if _, err := tls.X509KeyPair([]byte(secret.PEM), []byte(secret.KEY)); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your solution worked as expected, I think I must have been doing a bunch of extra processing since I was loading the Pem and Key files into variables first, encoding them and then passing the strings into jq then that parsed payload into the secretsmanager command. But replacing all of that with your example and loading the certs directly from files has fixed everything.

Thank you so much!